# Using Rails credentials within Gitlab CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have certain environment variables I need to utilize within Gitlab CI. I need these variables to be within Rails credentials, not stored on the Gitlab runners via settings.

I have been working on this for about a week now and am struggling to find a working solution. The ideal format would be able to use ERB-style markdown (i.e. - `<%= Rails.application.credentials[:my_credential] %>`) but of course I’m not able to preprocess the ERB and have Gitlab CI still function.

How can I utilize ENV vars on Gitlab CI that cannot be manually stored in the runner?

Comment: Whats the reason behind `These variables cannot be stored on the runners (via the GUI interface)`?

Comment: Good question Tony. I may not have made this clear in the question and will edit. Gitlab runners allow storage of environment variables, but for our business purposes in the app these need to be stored in Rails credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in [config files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) on your app. Specifically you can create a [./config.toml](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) file that can be used by the runners. You could then use ERB in the file to access your Rails credentials.  You would just need to set up a script that would parse it during the deploy.

Here is [an example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/da25731271dca8d8ddebab63c6ef148857b0bc17/files/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/gitaly-config.toml.erb) of one way of doing it.  Note that you need to add the `.erb` to the file extension.